# How to disable sudo authentication via fingerprint in fprint

Tags: 15.10, sudo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have installed fprint for my laptop (thinkpad t450s) and it works very well.

But i mainly want to use it for login, and being able to authenticate `sudo` with fingerprint is a great addition.

But when using `sudo` and i want to use my password instead of fingerprint i have to:

- wait 10 seconds
- swipe wrong finger

I know there isn't a way have both fingerprint and password at the same time (known issue at [fprint launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint))

Is there any way to disable fingerprint authentication **only** for `sudo`?

Answer (score 7):

You can easily reduce the timeout from 10 Seconds to 3 seconds by changing the timeout value in `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`. That would allow you to still use the fingerprint reader for sudo just with a less annoying timeout.

By default the authentification method for sudo matches your `common-auth` settings. But you can change that in the file `/etc/pam.d/sudo`.

- copy the file `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` to `/etc/pam.d/common-auth-nofingerprint`
- remove the line that references `pam_fprintd.so` from your new file.
- edit `/etc/pam.d/sudo` and use `@include common-auth-nofingerprint` instead of `@include common-auth`

/etc/pam.d/common-auth

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 # debug
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

/etc/pam.d/sudo

```
#%PAM-1.0

session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 user_readenv=0
session    required   pam_env.so readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale user_readenv=0
@include common-auth
@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive
```

For background information why fingerprint and password does not work in parallel see: https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/ubuntu/fprint in section `Known (minor) issues` - `1. No fingerprint and password at the same time`

Comment: ty, this worked for me under debian stretch

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is if you're using fprint version 1.92 (released around 2020 after this question was posted) or greater than you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop trying to use the fingerprint and switch to authentication via password: [commit that implemented this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd/-/commit/657f58fd648e35417ce7266b9c1558ce497dc179).